# memory leaks if using boost::asio::io_service::run in separate thread

Tags: boost-asio

I am trying to connect with a websocket using boost::asio library on win 7 32 bit. Normally, I get two memory leaks related openssl but If I am putting the boost::asio::io_service::run method in a separate thread, I am getting 6 memory leaks, out of which two leaks are of openssl lib.

Here is my code sample.

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp> 
#include <boost/asio/ssl.hpp>
#include <boost/array.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp> 
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vld.h>


boost::asio::io_service io_service; 
boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver resolver(io_service);
boost::array<char, 4096> buffer;
boost::thread thr; // thread object
boost::asio::ssl::context ctx(io_service, boost::asio::ssl::context::tlsv1_client);
boost::asio::ssl::stream<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket> ssl_sock(io_service, ctx);

void read_handler(const boost::system::error_code &ec, std::size_t bytes_transferred) 
{
    boost::system::error_code ec1;
    ssl_sock.lowest_layer().close(ec1);
}

void connect_handler(const boost::system::error_code &ec) 
{
    boost::system::error_code ec1;
    ssl_sock.handshake(boost::asio::ssl::stream<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket>::client, ec1);

    std::string m = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n"
                    "Sec-WebSocket-Key: GCeEn+pBGdrdj4mcrtBukA==\r\n"
                    "Upgrade: websocket\r\n"
                    "Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: x-webkit-deflate-frame"
                    "Connection: Upgrade\r\n"
                    "Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13\r\n"
                     "\r\n"; 

    if(!ec)
    { 
        boost::asio::write(ssl_sock, boost::asio::buffer(m)); 
        ssl_sock.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(buffer), read_handler); 
    }

    std::cout<<ec.message().c_str();
}

void resolve_handler(const boost::system::error_code &ec, boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator it) 
{ 
  if(!ec) 
  {
     ssl_sock.lowest_layer().async_connect(*it, connect_handler);
  }

  std::cout<<ec.message().c_str();
}

int main()
{
  ctx.set_verify_mode(boost::asio::ssl::verify_none);
  boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::query query("echo.websocket.org", "443"); 
  resolver.async_resolve(query, resolve_handler);
  thr = boost::thread( boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, &io_service) );
  thr.join();

 // io_service.run();
}
```

On read handler, I am just closing the connect. Overall, I am just creating and closing the connection. Socket is closing properly as the error code is 0.
Following are the memory leaks.

```
d:\cfiles\projects\winssl\openssl-1.0.1e\crypto\mem.c (79): WebsocketPPTest.exe!default_malloc_ex + 0xB bytes
    g:\websocketpptest\boost\asio\ssl\detail\impl\openssl_init.ipp (127): WebsocketPPTest.exe!boost::asio::ssl::detail::openssl_init_base::instance + 0x4A bytes
    g:\websocketpptest\boost\asio\ssl\detail\openssl_init.hpp (61): WebsocketPPTest.exe!boost::asio::ssl::detail::openssl_init<1>::openssl_init<1> + 0x5A bytes
    g:\websocketpptest\boost\asio\ssl\impl\context.ipp (171): WebsocketPPTest.exe!boost::asio::ssl::context::context + 0x6D bytes
    g:\websocketpptest\src\boostsocket.cpp (19): WebsocketPPTest.exe!`dynamic initializer for 'ctx'' + 0x2F bytes
    f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_x86\crt\src\crt0dat.c (873): WebsocketPPTest.exe!_initterm
    f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_x86\crt\src\crt0dat.c (288): WebsocketPPTest.exe!_cinit + 0xF bytes
    f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_x86\crt\src\crt0.c (262): WebsocketPPTest.exe!__tmainCRTStartup + 0x7 bytes
    f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_x86\crt\src\crt0.c (189): WebsocketPPTest.exe!mainCRTStartup
    0x76AF336A (File and line number not available): kernel32.dll!BaseThreadInitThunk + 0x12 bytes
    0x77309F72 (File and line number not available): ntdll.dll!RtlInitializeExceptionChain + 0x63 bytes
    0x77309F45 (File and line number not available): ntdll.dll!RtlInitializeExceptionChain + 0x36 bytes
  Data:
    00 00 00 00    40 68 71 00    01 00 00 00    04 00 00 00     ....@hq. ........
    E0 96 4C 00                                                  ..L..... ........


---------- Block 221 at 0x00716840: 16 bytes ----------
  Call Stack:
    d:\cfiles\projects\winssl\openssl-1.0.1e\crypto\mem.c (79): WebsocketPPTest.exe!default_malloc_ex + 0xB bytes
    g:\websocketpptest\boost\asio\ssl\detail\impl\openssl_init.ipp (127): WebsocketPPTest.exe!boost::asio::ssl::detail::openssl_init_base::instance + 0x4A bytes
    g:\websocketpptest\boost\asio\ssl\detail\openssl_init.hpp (61): WebsocketPPTest.exe!boost::asio::ssl::detail::openssl_init<1>::openssl_init<1> + 0x5A bytes
    g:\websocketpptest\boost\asio\ssl\impl\context.ipp (171): WebsocketPPTest.exe!boost::asio::ssl::context::context + 0x6D bytes
    g:\websocketpptest\src\boostsocket.cpp (19): WebsocketPPTest.exe!`dynamic initializer for 'ctx'' + 0x2F bytes
    f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_x86\crt\src\crt0dat.c (873): WebsocketPPTest.exe!_initterm
    f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_x86\crt\src\crt0dat.c (288): WebsocketPPTest.exe!_cinit + 0xF bytes
    f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_x86\crt\src\crt0.c (262): WebsocketPPTest.exe!__tmainCRTStartup + 0x7 bytes
    f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_x86\crt\src\crt0.c (189): WebsocketPPTest.exe!mainCRTStartup
    0x76AF336A (File and line number not available): kernel32.dll!BaseThreadInitThunk + 0x12 bytes
    0x77309F72 (File and line number not available): ntdll.dll!RtlInitializeExceptionChain + 0x63 bytes
    0x77309F45 (File and line number not available): ntdll.dll!RtlInitializeExceptionChain + 0x36 bytes
  Data:
    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00     ........ ........


---------- Block 5344 at 0x02A23008: 96 bytes ----------
  Call Stack:
  Data:
    E0 31 A2 02    40 16 3F 00    00 16 3F 00    08 00 00 00     .1..@.?. ..?.....
    10 00 00 00    00 00 00 00    08 00 00 00    00 02 00 00     ........ ........
    00 01 00 00    01 00 00 00    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00     ........ ........
    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00    1E 00 00 00    1C 00 00 00     ........ ........
    01 00 00 00    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00    01 00 00 00     ........ ........
    1C 00 00 00    00 00 00 00    1D 00 00 00    00 00 00 00     ........ ........


---------- Block 5346 at 0x02A230A8: 12 bytes ----------
  Call Stack:
  Data:
    D0 6A A2 02    00 00 00 00    E0 BE 01 00                    .j...... ........


---------- Block 5345 at 0x02A231E0: 64 bytes ----------
  Call Stack:
  Data:
    A8 30 A2 02    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00     .0...... ........
    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00     ........ ........
    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00     ........ ........
    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00     ........ ........


---------- Block 5343 at 0x02A26AD0: 400 bytes ----------
  Call Stack:
  Data:
    00 00 00 00    60 22 00 00    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00     ....`".. ........
    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00     ........ ........
    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00     ........ ........
    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00     ........ ........
    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00     ........ ........
    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00     ........ ........
    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00     ........ ........
    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00     ........ ........
    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00     ........ ........
    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00     ........ ........
    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00     ........ ........
    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00     ........ ........
    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00     ........ ........
    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00     ........ ........
    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00     ........ ........
    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00     ........ ........
```

Comment: what makes you think these are leaks and not just allocated once by OpenSSL? The call stacks seem to implicate `openssl_init.hpp`.

Comment: I used VLD to detect memory leaks. On closing the application normally i get following warning then the details,
WARNING: Visual Leak Detector detected memory leaks!
---------- Block 227 at 0x00545430: 20 bytes ----------
  Call Stack
...
...
...

Comment: what makes you think openssl is leaking memory? As I said, this appears to be memory allocated once for initialization. Does the leak ever grow in size?