# How to decipher memory leak reported by Visual Leak Detector

Tags: memory-leaks, openssl, boost-asio, visual-leak-detector

Can anyone help decipher the memory leak reported by Visual Leak Detector?

Is it somewhere in openssl?

Also why does it refer to files on drive `f:` when there is no such drive mapped?

A similar [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20067167/memory-leaks-if-using-boostasioio-servicerun-in-separate-thread) suggests it might be something to do with memory allocated once for initialization.

```
WARNING: Visual Leak Detector detected memory leaks!
---------- Block 364 at 0x005D2E38: 20 bytes ----------
  Leak Hash: 0x8FD6682B, Count: 1, Total 20 bytes
  Call Stack (TID 11424):
    0x771CE046 (File and line number not available): ntdll.dll!RtlAllocateHeap
    f:\dd\vctools\crt\crtw32\heap\malloc.c (58): utilities-test.exe!_heap_alloc_base
    f:\dd\vctools\crt\crtw32\misc\dbgheap.c (431): utilities-test.exe!_heap_alloc_dbg_impl + 0x9 bytes
    f:\dd\vctools\crt\crtw32\misc\dbgheap.c (239): utilities-test.exe!_nh_malloc_dbg_impl + 0x19 bytes
    f:\dd\vctools\crt\crtw32\misc\dbgheap.c (302): utilities-test.exe!_nh_malloc_dbg + 0x1D bytes
    f:\dd\vctools\crt\crtw32\misc\dbgmalloc.c (56): utilities-test.exe!malloc + 0x15 bytes
    d:\cfiles\projects\winssl\openssl-1.0.1e\crypto\mem.c (79): utilities-test.exe!default_malloc_ex + 0xB bytes
    c:\development\cots\boost\boost\asio\ssl\detail\impl\openssl_init.ipp (127): utilities-test.exe!boost::asio::ssl::detail
::openssl_init_base::instance + 0x3F bytes
    c:\development\cots\boost\boost\asio\ssl\detail\openssl_init.hpp (61): utilities-test.exe!boost::asio::ssl::detail::open
ssl_init<1>::openssl_init<1> + 0x9 bytes
    d:\server\programs\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xmemory0 (611): utilities-test.exe!`dynamic initializer for 'boost::asio::ssl
::detail::openssl_init<1>::instance_'' + 0xD bytes
    f:\dd\vctools\crt\crtw32\startup\crt0dat.c (955): utilities-test.exe!_initterm
    f:\dd\vctools\crt\crtw32\startup\crt0dat.c (308): utilities-test.exe!_cinit + 0xF bytes
    f:\dd\vctools\crt\crtw32\startup\crt0.c (237): utilities-test.exe!__tmainCRTStartup + 0x7 bytes
    f:\dd\vctools\crt\crtw32\startup\crt0.c (165): utilities-test.exe!mainCRTStartup
    0x76BA336A (File and line number not available): kernel32.dll!BaseThreadInitThunk + 0x12 bytes
    0x771D92B2 (File and line number not available): ntdll.dll!RtlInitializeExceptionChain + 0x63 bytes
    0x771D9285 (File and line number not available): ntdll.dll!RtlInitializeExceptionChain + 0x36 bytes
  Data:
    00 00 00 00    B8 2E 5D 00    01 00 00 00    04 00 00 00     ......]. ........
    50 E1 60 01                                                  P.`..... ........
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is it somewhere in openssl?

Yes, OpenSSL has known memory leaks. See, for example, OpenSSL [Issue #2561: Memory leak with SSL built-in compressions](https://rt.openssl.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=2561) and [How to properly uninitialize OpenSSL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29845527/608639).

This may (or may not) contribute to your issue.

There could be others.

---

> Can anyone help decipher the memory leak reported by Visual Leak Detector?

Sorry, I can't help there.

---

> Also why does it refer to files on drive f: when there is no such drive mapped?

Microsoft's debug record includes the path. See, for example, [Generating and Deploying Debug Symbols](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260783%28v=vs.60%29.aspx).

But it won't be helpful to you since you don't have Microsoft's build environment. Its safe to ignore.

Answer (score 0):

It points to f: because these paths are saved in the debug information. When CRT was built, the sources were placed on drive f:.

I think this is a leak that you should not (and can't) fix, it looks like a single time initialization.

Anyway also I'd suggest to try other 3rd party tool that find memory leaks, probably you would get more information.